# How can I read a value from a matrix I imported to anylogic using the table function?

Tags: anylogic

I imported a matric from excel to anylogic using the table function. See the screenshot [image]).

I am getting an error that says "type mismatch cannot convert from tablefunction to double"

I am trying to get a value from the matric (i.e, the value that corresponds to a particular row and column).

Thanks.

Comment: @benjamin Thanks for your swift response.

What I meant was that I imported the database already and accessed the database through the table function (I guess this is wrong).

I need help to access a value from the database. Please, help

Comment: Yes, this is wrong. Check the help on querying database values. Its all here: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/querying.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Table function, this is a database table. You can query data from it using the dbase wizard: put your cursor in a code field and click the wizard to get whatever data you want:
[image]

Many example models use the database, check them to see more on how to extract data (or see the help). See https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/querying.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution for working with excel files within AnyLogic:

1. Put your excel file into the same folder as your model.
2. Drag the "Excel File" element into Main.
   [image: 1]
3. In the properties of the Excel File element you've just added, select your file from the File dropdown menu.
4. You can make queries to the excel file like this:

   ```
    //For strings
    String value = excelFile.getCellStringValue("Sheet1",1,1);
    traceln(value);
   ```

   -> job_conditions

   ```
    //For numbers
    double value = excelFile.getCellNumericValue("Sheet1",2,2);
    traceln(value);
   ```

   -> 1.19

These functions have the form:

```
 excelFile.getCellNumericValue(String sheetName, int row index, int column index)
```

And alternatively, for the first argument, you can specify the sheet index (int) rather than the sheet name.

5.Go to https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/excel-file.html to see the full documentation for the Excel File element.